# Calculate amount on the basis of semiannual

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a question, I want merge my table data through date, all information provide in given table

If Aggregation = Semiannual

My table

Table-1

```
Amount |   TheDate      | Aggregation
-------+----------------+-------------    
100    |  2013-01-01    | Quaterly
100    |  2013-02-01    | Quaterly
100    |  2013-03-01    | Quaterly
100    |  2013-04-01    | Quaterly
100    |  2013-05-01    | Quaterly
100    |  2013-06-01    | Quaterly
200    |  2013-07-01    | Quaterly
200    |  2013-07-01    | Quaterly
200    |  2013-09-01    | Quaterly
200    |  2013-10-01    | Quaterly
200    |  2013-11-01    | Quaterly
200    |  2013-12-01    | Quaterly
```

I want result like this

```
Amount |   Date      | Aggregation
-------+-------------+-------------    
600    |  2013-06-01 | Quaterly 
1200   |  2013-12-01 | Quaterly
```

Query:

```
SELECT  
    DATEADD(MONTH, 2, DATEADD(quarter, DATEDIFF(quarter, 0, TheDate), 0)) AS Amount,
    ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT, SUM(Amount)) / 1000, 0) AS Total
FROM   
    myTble    
GROUP BY
    DATEADD(quarter, DATEDIFF(QQ, 0, TheDate), 0)
```

I'm trying above query but it only works for quarter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should group BY YEAR and `(MONTH-1)/6 = 0 for [1-6] or 1 for [7-12]`

```
SELECT SUM(Amount),
       MAX(TheDate)
FROM T
GROUP BY YEAR(TheDate),(MONTH(TheDate)-1)/6
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93b5e3/2)</kbd>

Comment: I have no experience with SQL Server, but in Microsoft Access, I had to change the forward slash (`/`) into a backward slash (`\``) to get the integer division behavior. Ultimately, the tweaked solution was what worked for me: `MONTH(TheDate)-1)\6`